# How to create a muli-set table overlap visualization in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, venn-diagram

Is it possible in R (preferable using ggplot2) to implement the following tabular set intersection visualization:

[image]

I had to pixelate column-headers and row labels but I guess the idea is still clear.

It's a bit similar to [UpsetR](https://github.com/hms-dbmi/UpSetR) but more table centric. Typically used venn diagrams don't apply here because it's too many sets (1 per column).

Data could be e.g.

```
depusers = frame_data(
~ person, ~ department, ~is_leader,
"Bob", "dev", TRUE,
"Bob", "accounting", FALSE,
"Marta", "dev", FALSE,
"Marta", "misc", FALSE,
"Max", "dev", FALSE,
"Max", "accounting", TRUE,
"Tim", "misc", TRUE,
"Tim", "security", FALSE,
"Horst", "security", FALSE,
"Tom", "management", TRUE
)
```

Columns should be the departments and the employees should go into the rows.

Comment: I see both the suggested `UpSetR` and your example here, and for both I question the use of lines to connect the dots: the lines imply an ordinal or continuous nature of the columns, which is misleading given your example data. The suggestion to depict correlation (using `pairs` or [`corrgram`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrgram/index.html)) is a little off, since it compares a set with itself, whereas your data is comparing two.

Comment: I see your point and I know the lines are arguable. Still in this context I like to include them. In fact the idea would be to make the department heads a bit bigger, so the lines might help to visually group the departments.

Comment: If you give a better description it'd be easier to help. How do you define size of circles? Is it departments on the x-axis? Is it important to have that white space between each person (presumably persons are on y-axis) to make it look like a table or it is fine as is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a great start M--, still I somehow missed the background tiles for visual alignment. An alternative imho slightly more pretty solution might be

```
bcknd_tiles = tidyr::expand(depusers, person, department) %>% inner_join(distinct(depusers, person) %>%
    arrange(person) %>%
    mutate(check_color = as.factor(row_number() %% 2)))

depusers %>% ggplot(aes(x = department, y = person, group = department)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = check_color), size = 3, color = "white", data = bcknd_tiles) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("1" = "white", "0" = "lightgray")) +
    geom_point(aes(colour = department, shape = "*", size = is_leader)) +
    scale_size_manual(values = c(3, 7)) +
    geom_line(aes(colour = department), size = 1) +
    scale_y_discrete(name = "person") +
    theme(legend.position = "none", axis.ticks = element_blank(), panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white')) +
    ggtitle("Company structure")
```

[image]

Comment: OK. It's now makes much more sense. `isLeader` defines the size. I can now edit my answer but you already got it I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be sufficient or at least a good starting point.

```
library(data.table) 
setDT(df)[, id := .GRP, by = person] #make an id for each person


library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=department, y=id,group = department)) + 
 geom_point(aes(colour = department, shape = "a"), size = 2) +
 geom_line(aes(colour = department), size = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="person",
                     breaks = seq(1,max(df$id)), labels = unique(df$person)) + 
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

This will give you:

[image]